# Is it feasible to install three skylights next to each other?

Tags: insulation, windows, waterproofing, structural, skylight

My contractors installed a new sloped roof and two new 16"x46" skylights spaced about 22" apart in my kitchen rehab.

I am contemplating having a third one installed in the middle. My question is whether this is feasible and safe to do in terms of installation and waterproofing? When the job is done there would only be about 2 inches between each window from the outside. My contractor says it is not safe, but when his sub contractor roofer/window guy came out he told me it was safe and 100% doable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to think that it's not feasible. The only concerns are weather sealing, and that can be done either with units designed to be installed in multiples (with combination flashing) or by a roofer who knows their business well.

It's as simple as that.